# C# Number Literals

Tags: c#, performance, literals

With this method declaration (no overloads):

```
void Method(double d)
{
  // do something with d
}
```

Is there a (performance) difference at runtime between

```
void Main()
{
    Method(1);
    Method(1.0);
}
```

or does the compiler automatically convert the int literal to a double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it. C# 3.0 generates the following IL for your first call:

```
ldc.r8 1.
call instance void ConsoleApplication1.Program::Method(float64)
```

So, no runtime conversion.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler will implicitly convert the int to a double.

There will be no penalty.

Comment: To add to this: You can always use Reflector to look at the resulting IL or what it looks like when converted back into C#.